# problema com namespace ao rodar projeto

Tags: php, namespace

Não consigo fazer esse código rodar, estou iniciando com o namespace e gostaria me dessem uma dica para eu continuar meus estudos.

Primeira classe

```
<?php

namespace view\classes;
class View {
    public function visualizar()
    {
        echo 'visualizar';
    }
}
```

Segunda classe

```
<?php
namespace view\classes;
class ScriptView extends ViewClass{

    public function visualizar(){
        echo 'visualizar';
    }

}

$script = new ViewClass();
echo $script ->visualizar();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por ter dois arquivos distintos, o php não irá reconhecer automaticamente ambas as classes.

É preciso utilizar um autoload para uma classe "enxegar" a outra.

Estrutura de pasta:

```
view
 |_ classes
     |_ View.php
     |_ ScripView.php
index.php
```

No seu arquivo `index.php` implemente o autoload e voa-lá!

```
<?php

spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
spl_autoload_register();

use view\classes\ScriptView;

$script = new ScriptView(); // ou new view\classes\ScriptView();
$script->visualizar();
```

Nesse caso observe que:

1. A estrutura de pastas segue exatamente o definido pelo namespace
2. Alguns sistemas operacionais diferem maiúsculas de minúsculas, por isso, tente manter um padrão de nomes entre diretórios e namespaces.
3. Sua classe `ScriptView` no exemplo extende `ViewClass`, que não existe.

Mais informações:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.autoload.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: Valeu, muito obrigado cara!

Answer (score 1):

Onde está definição da classe "ViewClass"? Assumindo que você escreveu errado você extendendo a **View** não vai funcionar, pois o arquivo que contém sua definição não está sendo incluindo no arquivo que usa (classe ScriptView).

No arquivo de definição da classe **ScriptView** você precisa incluir o arquivo de definição da classe **View**.

Como você vai utilizar *namespace* você deve usar o recurso de **autoloading** que fará o trabalho de incluir esses arquivos pra você usando o namespace como máscaras aos diretórios.

Por exemplo:

**namespace MyFramework\Base\Controller;**

Quando você utilizar a classe que estiver nesse namespace, no exemplo Controller, o PHP vai fornecer o nome dessa classe a qual quer acesso e você vai apontar para o arquivo físico que vai ser incluido:

**MyFramework/Base/Controller.php** - *(essas definições de extensão e diretórios extras podem ser definidos no seu autoload).*

[Aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.spl-autoload-register.php) você encontra o link da função que permite registrar o autoload e exemplo de como implementar o seu próprio autoload.

Além do fato de não precisar incluir os seus arquivos manualmente você tem um ganho em performance por não incluir classes não utilizadas, ou seja, o carregamento dessas classes vai ser sob demanda.

Comment: Valeu, muito obrigado.