# Como usar namespace numa Classe?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, amazon-aws, namespace

Eu estou a usar o [AWS SDK for PHP da Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html) e para isso eu preciso da classe `S3Client`.

Eu estava a ver um exemplo de upload para a amazon e fazia assim:

```
require '../aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$s3 = S3Client::factory($config);
```

Agora queria incluir o `S3Client` na minha classe de comunicação com a amazon (`ConnectionCloud`).
O problema é que dá o seguinte erro:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'S3Client' not found

Como é que eu declaro a classe 
 'S3Client' dentro da minha classe `ConnectionCloud`?

Comment: Até hoje to tentando entender o funcionamento desses name spaces e autoloader, sempre da algum tipo de erro quando vou usar, se alguem tiver um bom tutorial pra indicar estou aceitando

Comment: vocÊ já tentou remover o use e fazer assim:
$s3 = Aws\S3\S3Cliente::factory($config);

Comment: @Kaminary dá: 
> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Aws\\S3\\S3Cliente' not found

Comment: Consegue instanciar colocando uma barra no início do namespace? Assim: `use \Aws\S3\S3Client;`

Comment: Não porque dentro da minha Classe não sei como instanciar a `S3Client`.

Comment: Qual o conteúdo de **aws-autoloader.php**?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/installation.html#installing-via-zip

Comment: Certo... E como você está tentando fazer na sua classe.

Comment: Tentei fazer como no exemplo acima, mas não funciona. 
Na minha classe ponho só `$s3 = S3Client::factory($config);` o resto eu ponho no script PHP geral antes de chamar a minha classe.

Comment: E o arquivo de autoload está sendo incluído **antes** da sua classe ser instanciada?

Comment: Sim Bruno Augusto

Comment: Estranho porque eu copiei os arquivos aqui e testei incluindo o arquivo de autoload e quando fazendo um var_dump() dessa *factory* os dados apareceram direitinho. Restam ainda duas possibilidades: 1) O arquivo de autoload não está sendo carregado; 2) Apesar de pouco provável, seu PHP ser anterior à versão 5.3, que foi quando a constante mágica **__DIR__** utilizada pelo autoloader foi introduzida.

Comment: Estou a trabalhar com a última versão do PHP

Comment: E o arquivo está sendo incluído com sucesso? Caso contrário o spl_autpload_register() no final dele não será executado. Mais uma possibilidade: Por acaso você usa **__autoload()** ao invés de spl_autoload_register()?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18565/discussion-between-jorge-b-and-bruno-augusto).

Comment: @JorgeB. se você estiver usando algum *namespace* ná página em questão, (*namespace JorgeB;*) talvez precise de uma barra na frente `\Aws\S3\S3Client;`

Comment: @RodrigoBorth veja se minha resposta ajuda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O seu erro provavelmente está na implementação do autoload que não está encontrando a classe solicitada no `use`.

Utilize o [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) para gerenciar suas dependências e classes ao trabalhar com namespaces em PHP. Como ele já inclui um autoload que suporta os padrões da comunidade, você não terá maiores problemas ao trabalhar bibliotecas externas:

Arquivo `index.php`

```
<?php

// Autoload do Composer
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Instancio uma classe qualquer
$cloud = new MyApp\CloudProvider();

echo $cloud->getProviderClass();
```

Classe `CloudProvider.php`

```
<?php namespace MyApp;

// Minha classe está acessando uma biblioteca externa, localizada na pasta vendor
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

class CloudProvider {

    protected $provider;

    public function __construct($config)
    {
        $this->provider = S3Client::factory($config);
    }

    public function getProviderClass()
    {
        return get_class($this->provider);
    }

}
```

`composer.json`: configuração do Composer

```
{
    "require": {
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.7.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "MyApp\\": "" }
    }
}
```

Exemplo: https://github.com/gmsantos/namespace

### Explicação

Para fazer uso de namespaces em PHP de forma automática, sem precisar incluir arquivos via `require`,  precisamos implementar no PHP um `autoload` e seguir uma convenção para nomear nossas classes e a estrutura de pastas. [Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/29088/4751) temos uma implementação simples de autoload.

Observe que mesmo em um implementação simples, existe um padrão para nomearmos as classes. A comunidade PHP adota alguns padrões com regras específicas conhecidas como PSR-0 e PSR-4 ([mais sobre PSR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32295/o-que-significa-psr/32302#32302)) para nomearmos classes e pastas.

Para não precisarmos implementar o autoload em todos nosso projetos manualmente, podemos usar uma implementação pronta. A mais utilizada é o [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), que além de ser compatível com os padrões acima, é também um [gerenciador de dependência](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_gestor_de_pacotes).

Após instalar o Composer, basta criar um arquivo `composer.json` e dentro dele configurar o `namespace` da sua aplicação e o path dos seus arquivos. Ele irá criar uma pasta `vendor` no seu projeto, que incluí as dependências do seu projeto e um `autoload.php` pronto pra usar.

Mais informação de como instalar o Composer e utilizá você pode encontrar [aqui](http://br.phptherightway.com/#gerenciamento_de_dependencia) e também na [documentação<sup>en</sup>](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

Comment: Eu ainda acho que ele não estava incluindo o arquivo com o mapeamento class/path (que já incluia um autoloader) ou tinha algum outro autoloader, muito provavelmente um definido com a função __autoload(), sobrescrevendo esse um.