# Como listar arquivos em um diretório?

Tags: php, classes, orientação-a-objetos

Utilizo o seguinte código :

```
$path = 'pasta_desejada';
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
foreach ($dir as $fileInfo) {
    $ext = strtolower( $fileInfo->getExtension() );
    if( in_array( $ext, $types ) ) echo $fileInfo->getFilename();
}
```

Porem ao executar logo após o primeiro arquivo aparece um '..' e como minha ideia é fazer ele ler e dar `include` em cada arquivo (pois são classes) esses '..' dão erro.

Alguém sabe como arrumar ou conhece outro método para meu objetivo?

Comment: Augusto, evite usar snippet para códigos que não sejam executáveis como html + javascript e/ou css são..

Comment: Mas ao colar o código da problema, só a primeira linha entra...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema do autoload, irei responder minha própia pergunta, pois se mais alguem precisar pode usar ...

```
function autoLoad() {
    blockAutoLoad('class/'); // invoca metodo de autoload
}


function blockAutoLoad($path) {
    include_once ($path . 'sysConnect.php'); // inclui a connect pois todas extend dela
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator($path); // acessa dir
    foreach ($dir as $fileInfo) { // pega file info
    //echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "<br />";
    $arrayFileName = explode('.', $fileInfo->getFilename()); // tira os .
    foreach ($arrayFileName as $sl) { // foreach
            if($sl =='' || $sl == 'php' || $sl == ' ' || $sl == 'teste' || $sl == 'DS_Store') { // limpa string
                //echo $sl . '<br />';
            } else {
                //echo $sl . '<br />'; // exibe nome de arquivos
                include_once ($path . $sl . '.php'); // inclui classe
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero poder ajudar alguém ... XD

Comment: Augusto, novamente dizendo, evite usar snippet se o código não for executável, como html com css e algum javascript combinados.

Answer (score 2):

Verifique se `$fileInfo` é um arquivo ou diretório, dois métodos podem fazer isso dependendo do caso um [isDir()](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.isdir.php) e ou [isFile()](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.isfile.php).

```
foreach ($dir as $fileInfo) {
   if(!$fileInfo->isDir()){
      $ext = strtolower( $fileInfo->getExtension() );
      if( in_array( $ext, $types ) ) echo $fileInfo->getFilename();
   }
}
```

Comment: n deu crt, ele n exibe nd ...

Comment: @AugustoFurlan e se vc mudar o if por `if (!$fileinfo->isDot())`

Comment: não da certo ...

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o método [`isDot()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/directoryiterator.isdot.php) para verificar se o item é um navegador entre diretórios.

```
<?php

$path = 'pasta_desejada';
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);

foreach ($dir as $item) {
    if (! $item->isDot()) {
        // Faz algo
    }
}
```

Mas já que você está dando *include* em vários arquivos, talvez o que você procure é o [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php).

Com ele você conseguirá entrar nos subdiretórios e dar o *include* nos arquivos (claro, verificando antes se são arquivos):

```
<?php

$path = 'pasta_desejada';
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator ($path);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);

foreach ($iterator as $item) {
    // Verifica se é um arquivo
    if ($item->isFile()) {
        // Faz algo
    }
}
```

Já que são classes, [talvez você queira filtrar pela extensão PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#97228). Para isso você pode combinar com mais outros `Iterators`, como o [`RegexIterator`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.regexiterator.php)

```
<?php

$path = 'pasta_desejada';
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator ($path);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);

$filterIterator= new RegexIterator(
    $iterator , 
    '/^.+\.php$/i', 
    RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH
);

foreach ($iterator as $item) {
    // Verifica se é um arquivo
    if ($item->isFile()) {
        // Faz algo
    }
}
```

Existem várias formas para fazer isso. Só por favor não tente reinventar a roda. Se está tentando fazer um *autoloader*, ao invés disso tente usar o [Composer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40051/como-usar-namespace-numa-classe/40511#40511) ;)