# Namespace em PHP Não funciona

Tags: php, namespace

Olá, estou tentando utilizar o `namespace` e o `use` do PHP mas está resultando em Not found

Erro: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'app\lib\Teste' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 5`

index.php:

```
<?php

require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use \app\lib\Teste;

new Teste();

?>
```

htdocs/app/lib/Teste.php

```
<?php

namespace app\lib;


class Teste {


    public function __construct() {
        echo "Hello world";
    }

}


?>
```

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Pra poder utilizar isto: `new Teste();`, primeiro se faz isto: `use \app\lib\Teste AS Teste;`, este é o primeiro problema, veja se funciona.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta, já tentei isto e ainda nada.

Comment: Posta o composer.json também

Comment: `{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.3"
    }
}
`

Comment: Vê se te ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40051/como-usar-namespace-numa-classe/40511#40511

Comment: Opa obrigado pela resposta, ainda nada , tentei fazer isto: ``new app\lib\Teste();`` e ainda não foi, não estou entendendo o porque do not found pois existe sim este diretório e esta classe.

Comment: tenta chamar \app\lib apenas

Comment: Se eu chamo apenas o ``use app\lib;`` e após isso chamo o ``new Teste();`` retorna isto: ``Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Teste' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 13`` , eu acho que deve ser algum problema de extensão .php no use ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Você precisa definir o autoload no seu composer.json primeiro

Comment: Se você esta utilizando o composer você deve rodar o composer dump-autoload depois de criar as classes para que o mapeamento seja atualizado.

Answer (score -1):

Fiz algumas simulações e funcionou, talvez o problema tenha sido na hora de instanciar, teste algo assim e mostre o que retornou:

```
use app\lib\Teste as T;

    public $teste;

    $this->teste = new T();
```