# Criando e usando Bibliotecas no Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, laravel-5

Sou novo em relação ao Laravel 5.1 (venho do CodeIgniter) e tenho bibliotecas próprias que gostaria de implementar no mesmo. No CodeIgniter, temos a pasta `libraries` onde eu posso jogar todas as minhas bibliotecas lá e se caso eu precise da mesma só preciso carregá-las usando um `$this->load->library('minha_biblioteca');`

Como eu posso utilizar esta mesma biblioteca e seus métodos dentro do Laravel? Onde eu devo colocar a mesma e como chamá-la em meus controladores.

Answer (score 2):

Ao utilizar o Laravel ou qualquer outro Framework moderno você notará muitas diferenças com o Codeigniter. Ele "parou" no tempo e não acompanhou as novidades que surgiram ao longo dos anos na comunidade PHP.

Atualmente, para bibliotecas externas os códigos são carregados a partir do [*Autoload* do PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29086/problema-com-namespace-ao-rodar-projeto/29088#29088), seguindo um padrão de estrutura de diretórios ([PSR-4 ou PSR-0](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32302/4751)) para o carregamento automático dessas classes. Isso tudo é feito pelo Composer e o [Laravel já utiliza ele](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/composer.json).

Para utilizar seus códigos antigos, você precisa modificar todos eles para eliminar as dependências com o Codeigniter e aplicar *Namespaces* nas suas classes de forma que sejam compatíveis com a PSR-4.

O diretório que você pode fazer isso pode ser qualquer um, desde que ele esteja definido no seu `composer.json`:

```
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "MinhaBiblioteca\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

Estrutura de diretórios

```
src
 |_ Utils
     |_ View.php
     |_ ScripView.php
```

Para usar uma classe própria chamada `View.php` você pode incluir ela no `use` logo após o *namespace* e importar através do Type Hint dos Controllers do Laravel:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use MinhaBiblioteca\Utils\View;

class MeuController extends Controller
{

    public function getIndex()
    {
        $v = new View();
    }

}
```